# Webapps, where (my) questions fail to get an answer

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new in the arena of Stack Exchange sites. My oldest subscription is at Stack Overflow and 
is only ten months old. Now I subscribe to six sites. I am still amazed by the beauty of Stack Exchange.

Anyway, now that I have introduced myself, let us come to the point. It appears to me that in webapps, I am rather unlucky.
In the other sites, I got very good answers almost within the day, if not within the hours. It is a different story in Webapps.

In webapps, I have asked three questions so far,

1. [Why does Unicode searching fail in Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/why-does-unicode-searching-fail-in-google-calendar)
2. [Custom question for people wishing to join groups in new Google
   groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/custom-question-for-people-wishing-to-join-groups-in-new-google-groups)
3. [Deleting old versions of files from Google site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/deleting-old-versions-of-files-from-google-site)

None of these secured me an answer. Only one of these got up voted. For others, nobody even bothered to answer (not even up vote or down vote, thanks for the second one). There have been some views.

May be I will get a bunch of [Tumbleweed badges](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) soon. But I am not exactly looking for that [dubious distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbleweed).

What could have gone wrong here? My questions were not worthy of answers? But they are my real life problems. 
And so far, I have never been chastised for asking foolish questions.

One thing in common, all the questions are related to Google applications.

Any inputs, suggestions, and even comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for posting here on Meta !! +1 for doing so.

Comment: "I have never been chastised for asking foolish questions". Lucky you.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Well, so far. Or perhaps I forgot those incidents, _conveniently_.

Comment: I've found that updating your questions and answers with more or better information, better structure, some screenshots will result in people trying to reproduce your problem and may get you an answer eventually. Why-questions are not really good for Webapps.se, but "How do I"-questions are more answerable.

Comment: @user-99572-is-fine Thanks for your constructive suggestion. I have edited all the three questions as advised by you - edited subjects, changed contents, added screen shots. I have kept the subjects in the above _meta_ question unchanged though. But the links take one to the edited question. Let us hope for the best.

Comment: @mma one more thing: editing your question and improving it leads it to being displayed on the main page more often --> more eyeballs, better chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @user-99572-is-fine, I already got answer/suggestive hints for two, but secured a Tumbleweed badge for the third :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its very possible that, unfortunately, it's simply that someone doesn't know. While I'm not massively active on Web Apps, I've had questions on Super User (which is much more active) sit for ages, and eventually get answered.

It isn't you or the question. It's just the unfortunate lack of intersection between the question and someone who feels they can actually give a quality answer. Maybe eventually someone *will* work out what's the right answer, and earn themselves a shiny Necromancer badge, but it very definitely isn't a user or system issue.

Comment: @MMA Stack Overflow gets 6 million visits/day. Ask Ubuntu gets 218k visits/day. WebApps gets only 48k visits/day. It might take some time, it's a question of math.

Comment: @journeyman-geek do you think I will have better luck if I move my queries to http://superuser.com/? If the answer is yes, what will be best way to do that without cross posting?

Comment: this is off topic for SU, really. I gave SU as an example since thats where I primarily post

Answer (score 16):

Most of your questions are such that it's really not possible to be answered.

First:

> Why does Unicode searching fail in Google Calendar?
>
> But when I search with a non English Unicode word, the search is not successful.

This seems mainly like a bug with Google Calendar and, honestly, I don't think there's way anyone can answer, unless he's got access to Calendar search codebase.

The second question - is as you said:

> However, in the new Google groups, I failed to find this feature, even after repeated searching.

A feature has been removed. I'm not sure if saying "Yes, it's been removed" would be a valid answer, and your related question

> But why remove a feature?

cannot be answered by anyone except for Product Management team. There can be a variety of reasons *why* a feature can be removed

> Deleting old versions of files from Google site

You third question also goes into the same category of "there's no way of doing so yet" - and unless conclusively documented, people generally give the silent treatment - implying "No" than a definitive "there's no way to do so".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Perhaps I was being a bit hard when making my post. Actually, in a situation with no comments, no votes and almost no views, you understand my frustration. The discussions you have made above would suffice in the actual posts.